# objective-c: array enumeration using keypath

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have an array of Person objects (which has a number of attributes). I want to make another array with just the Person's "fullname" attribute. Is there a simple way to do this, other than the obvious one: iterate over the original array, and copy over the fullname one-by-one into another array? Can we do this initWithArray: and tell it to use the object's fullname property when copying?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSArray indeed has built-in method for that:

```
NSArray *nameArray = [personArray valueForKey:@"fullname"];
```

Comment: Isnt `valueForKeyPath` an NSDictionary method?